# Unable to play a video using autoplay loop features inside <video> tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using a video tag in which I have downloaded a timelapse video from Pexel and have included the mp4 file inside VS Code folder. After I type autoplay, loop inside the video tag, the video is not playing. Here is the code:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
       <source src="Flower.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

The video remains static. What could be the problem with the video tag? Is the format of the video tag, ok?
I did also type like this:

```
   <video autoplay loop src="Flower.mp4"></video>
```

But the same old result is being shown i.e. video is static.
Please suggest as to what should be done here.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the unsupported video format by the browser. Can you try converting the video to a different format such as H.264 or WebM and see if it works? Also, make sure the video file is in the correct path specified in the 'src' attribute of the video tag. If the video file is still not playing, try adding the 'controls' attribute to the video tag to check if the issue is with the autoplay and loop attributes.

```html
<video autoplay loop controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"></video>
```

By adding the 'controls' attribute, you can check if the issue is with the autoplay and loop attributes, or if the video file is simply not playing.

Update:

```js
 const video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
 video.loop = true;
 video.autoplay = true;
 video.play();
```

```html
  <video id="myVideo" controls>
      <source
        src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

Comment: Hi Enrique, thank you for the help. It is working but for that I have to go and play it and then from there it is autoplaying on loop. Can we get rid of the individual playing by the user?

Comment: @AnkanChanda The loop and autoplay attributes for the HTML5 video element work in most modern browsers, but the behavior may vary across different devices and platforms. To ensure maximum compatibility, it's recommended to use JavaScript to control the playback behavior of the video, rather than relying solely on the loop and autoplay attributes. I update the answer.